# Hierarchical queries in MySQL to retrieve a joined table

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables.
Table: articles

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default Extra                       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-------+---------------+
| articleid    | int(14)      | NO   | MUL | NULL      |             |
| categoryid   | int(14)      | NO   |     | NULL
```

Table: categories

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cat_parent| int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| cat_child | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| sortorder | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the query from the mysql site:

```
   SELECT t1.articleid AS lev1, t2.articleid as lev2, t3.articleid as lev3, t4.articleid as lev4
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.child = t1.cat_parent
LEFT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.child = t2.cat_parent
LEFT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.child = t3.cat_parent
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve ALL articleids based on the parent or child

I have read about this on [mysql site](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles) but I do not understand how to apply the concept when I have 2 tables. The query I modified is from that page I linked to.

Comment: You've not linked to a single article, you've linked to an index of about 200 of them. Can you edit your link to indicate which article you mean?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement a hierarchy using just a parent node. As far as I know, this requires recursive SQL to implement correctly, and I don't know to what degree MySQL supports that. It might be better to use the Nested Set algorithm instead - it breaks a hierarchy down into just comparison operators, and is much more suited to relational databases. Search for "MySQL PHP nested set" in a search engine to see examples.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your question, this isn't a true recursive query problem.  It's difficult to do true hierarchical queries in MySQL because of the lack of support for CONNECT BY (like Oracle) or WITH (common table expressions in Postgres.)  You can sort of do recursive queries by using a stored procedure, but I think what you want is to just select all of the articles in the category of either the parent or child category?

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to the original question.  If I understand your question correctly, this should do it.  Replace {the id of the article you start with} with your value and you will get back the articleid values of everything that's in either the child or parent categories of the category that article is in.

Note that this isn't a true recursive or hierarchical query, which is very tricky to do in MySQL and the best strategy is usually to avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

If this isn't sufficient and you do really need to do a hierarchical query, see [this answer.](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/)

I hope that helps!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a1.articleid)
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.categoryid = a.categoryid
LEFT JOIN articles a1 ON a1.categoryid = a.categoryid OR a1.categoryid = c.cat_parent OR a1.categoryid = c.cat_child
WHERE a.articleid = {the id of the article you start with}
```